# Finding conditions for an inequality, positive semi definite

Tags: sequences-and-series, positive-definite, time-series

I want to prove that the sequence:

$$ ( 2 + \psi^2 ; \psi ) $$ is positive semi definite for $|\psi | < 1$, and ideally find conditions on $\psi$ about when it isn't.

Recall that for a sequence, the definition of being positive semi definite is:
$\forall t_1, \cdots, t_n \in \mathbb T, \forall a_1, \cdots, a_n \in \mathbb R^*\colon$
$$
\sum_1^n \sum_k^n s_{t_j-t_k} a_j a_k \geq 0
$$

---

My attempt:

I reduced the problem to finding a condition on $\psi$ such that this inequality hold (in that case, the sequence is not positive semi definite).

$$ 2A + 2B - 2 \psi A B + \psi^2 [ A + B ] < 0 $$

my problem is that $A,B$ can be any number and I don't know how to tackle that problem. I computed the roots (potentially complex) but it isn't instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually I had a brilliant idea. Instead of looking at the sequence, I looked at the derived matrix.

> Proving a sequence is positive definite is equivalent to proving the
>   Toeplitz matrix is positive definite.

In other words, I want to prove that $M$ is semi positive definite where: 
$$ 
M = \begin{bmatrix} 2+ \psi^2 & -\psi \\ -\psi & 2+\psi^2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I computed the eigenvalues with the characteristic polynomial, and in fact, there is no real roots thus the matrix is positive definite.

**Then, this results in having my original sequence positive definite $\forall \psi$!**

---

**EDIT**

OFC there are real roots because the matrix is symetric (spectral theorem). I did a small mistake computing the determinant ( the formula is ad-bc ) and then I found those two roots :

$$ r_1 = \psi^2 + \psi + 2, \qquad r_2 = \psi^2 - \psi + 2 $$

which polynomials in $\psi$ don't have any root. So, the roots never get negative, then the matrix has 2 positive eigenvalues.